# Access dynamic JSON name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am able to read JSON data from javascript with `json.data.groupID[0].name`. The `groupID` is dynamic. I tried to do it with this and it doesn't work:

```
aa = 'groupA';
json.data[aa[0][name]]
```

How can I get the json data with the dynamic groupID name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
json.data[aa][0][name]
```